# Git pull after merge without result

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitlab, git-merge, git-pull

I did a merge on branch a and b (a -> b). I'm on branch b on my computer - ubuntu 19.04 and I'm trying to pull latest version of branch, but it shows me "Already up to data". Files in folder are from before merge. Why it shows me this message and how to pull content from branch after merging it with other branch?

Repository is on GitLab.

Comment: "I did a merge on branch a and b" Please show the exact commands that you performed. Also show the current state of your history.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I did that via webpage so I can't show you commands. History - you mean logs from both branches or just b?

Answer (score 0):

After executing:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git pull origin b
```

my branch have content after merge.